# Вывод файлов из директории с определённым расширением

Tags: файлы, php

Ребят, нужна помощь:) Нужно как-то обрезать полный путь до названия файла
Вот что говорит браузер

> ```
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/about.php 
> размер 3066  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/about_page.php 
> размер 2889  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/auth.php 
> размер 3005  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/error_message.php 
> размер 249  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/footer.php 
> размер 783  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/main.php 
> размер 4179  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/register.php 
> размер 2968  
> Z:/home/test1.ru/www/template/default/static.php
> размер 618
> ```

Мне нужно чтобы путь не отображался, а отображался чисто название файла, например так:

> about.php

Сделал сначала на explode, и ничего не получилось)

Вот PHP код:

```
  foreach (glob(MAIN."/template/default/*.php") as $filename) {
       echo "$filename размер " . filesize($filename) . "\n<br>";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename=basename($filename);
```